# TWIG Date Time locale language

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, locale, twig

in TWIG file

```
     {{ comments.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}

     Thursday, July 25, 2013
```

displays default locale English. How can we display in other language format. German, Turkish etc.

Comment: AFAIK you have to write the translation yourself and then apply the `trans` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Twig function `locale_date` using the following code snippet. It reads the current locale from Symfonys `Request` object and uses
PHPs `IntlDateFormatter` to format the given date.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class LocaleDateExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getFilters(): array {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('locale_date', [$this, 'localeDate']),
        ];
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('locale_date', [$this, 'localeDate']),
        ];
    }

    public function localeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date, $format) {
        $formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
                $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getLocale(),
                \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                \IntlDateFormatter::NONE
        );
        $formatter->setPattern($format);
        return $formatter->format($date);
    }

}
```

Usage in Twig:

```
{{ blog.createdAt|locale_date('d. MMMM yyyy') }}
```

The Twig variable must be a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score -4):

Simply set the needed format

```
{{ comments.created|date('d.m.Y') }}
```

Comment: It won't change `Thursday` or `July` to the German or Turkish version